# Flutter - How can I fit each image in a horizontal ListView to screen?

Tags: flutter

I created a horizontal ListView contains lots of images, but each image in ListView does not fit the screen (sometimes I have to scroll to see the rest of it and of course a part of the next image). How can I stretch each image fit the screen and scroll to see the next image 
(next image has to fit the screen too)

UPDATE EXAMPLE
[image: Horizontal Image ListView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant was carousel widget, never heard about it before. I was new at Mobile development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DecorationImage` with `BoxFit.fill`

Example:

```
Container(
          width: 64.0,
          height: 64.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: new DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: new NetworkImage('my_url.jpg')
            )
        ))
```

Comment: No, I mean stretch each image in horizontal ListView to screen not just single image

Comment: Can you have a mockup or screenshot. I don't know what do you mean?

Comment: Updated example

Comment: So I think you can set the width of image equal screen size. To get the width of screensize. You can use

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for Horizontal list view with perfect fit images.

```
 Container(
            height: 275,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: furnitures.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Map furniture = furnitures[index];

                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context){
                            return Details();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 275,
                      width: 280,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            furniture['name'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "${furniture["img"]}",
                              height: 240,
                              width: 280,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },

            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to achieve this. Simply by typing `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` which gives you the width of the device screen then you assign to the width of the image